# How can I solve my recursion equation?

Tags: recursion

How can I solve the recursion equation given below?

I doubt there have no solution for the recursion equation because this is circulating recucrsion equation.

```
RSolve[
 If[n >= 3, 
  S[n] == ((c/m + 1)*S[n - 1] - q*S[n - 2])/q, 
  {S[2] == (S[1]*(c + m))/(m*q) - 2*S[0], 
   S[1] == ((S[0] - 1)*(c/m + 1) + 2*q)/q - S[n]}],
 S[n], n]
```

Comment: Something is wrong in the definition of the boundary term `S[1]`, are you sure that there is `S[n]`?

Comment: @user69748 Am I missing something or there should be a boundary condition `S[0]` ?

Answer (score 3):

I still think that the condition `S[0]` should be included in your code, but nevertheless I obtained some results which might be helpful in your situation. So, two approaches:

```
Solve[
 {Assuming[n >= 3, S[n] == ((c/m + 1)*S[n - 1] - q*S[n - 2])/q], 
 S[2] == (S[1]*(c + m))/(m*q) - 2*S[0], 
 S[1] == ((S[0] - 1)*(c/m + 1) + 2*q)/q - S[n]}, 
S[n], n] // FullSimplify
```

Output:

> $\left\{\left\{S(n)\to \frac{c (S(0)-1)+m (-q (S(1)-2)+S(0)-1)}{m q}\right\}\right\}$

---

```
Reduce[
  {Assuming[n >= 3, S[n] == ((c/m + 1)*S[n - 1] - q*S[n - 2])/q],
  S[2] == (S[1]*(c + m))/(m*q) - 2*S[0], 
  S[1] == ((S[0] - 1)*(c/m + 1) + 2*q)/q - S[n]}, 
S[n]] // FullSimplify
```

Output:

> ```
> m q != 0 && ((S[-2 + n] + S[n] == ((c + m) S[-1 + n])/(
>   m q) && ((c + m + (m q (-2 + S[1] - S[-2 + n]))/(
>        1 - S[0] + S[-1 + n]) == 
>       0 && (4 S[0] + S[2] + Sqrt[
>          8 (-2 + S[1]) S[1] + (2 + S[2])^2 - 8 S[1] S[-2 + n] + 
>           4 S[-1 + n] (2 + S[2] + S[-1 + n])] == 2 + 2 S[-1 + n] ||
>         2 + 2 S[-1 + n] + Sqrt[
>          8 (-2 + S[1]) S[1] + (2 + S[2])^2 - 8 S[1] S[-2 + n] + 
>           4 S[-1 + n] (2 + S[2] + S[-1 + n])] == 
>         4 S[0] + S[2])) || (c == (
>       m (-2 + q (2 + S[2]) - S[-2 + n] + 2 q S[-1 + n]))/(
>       2 + S[-2 + n]) && S[0] == 1 + S[-1 + n] && 
>      S[1] == 2 + S[-2 + n] && 2 + S[-2 + n] != 0))) || (S[0] == 
>    1 + S[-1 + n] && S[1] == 0 && 2 + S[-2 + n] == 0 && 
>   2 + S[2] + 2 S[-1 + n] == 0 && 
>   S[n] == 2 + ((c + m) S[-1 + n])/(m q)))
> ```

I know this is not a pretty nor elegant answer, but should give you a kick-start.